# Too slow PhantomJS script

Tags: php, ajax, phantomjs

I need to get the items(with selector a[id=test]) from the page that is loaded by ajax. For this I use phantomjs.

In PHP:

```
$phantom_path = '/usr/bin/phantomjs';
$names  = shell_exec("$phantom_path model/phantomscript-names.js $url");
```

in phantomjs i received items:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    url = system.args[1];

page.open(url, function(status) {
    page.injectJs('jquery-2.1.4.min.js');
    var links = page.evaluate(function() {
        return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[id=test]'), function(link) {
            return link.innerText;
        });
    });
    console.log(links.join('\n'));
    phantom.exit();
});
```

the script runs for about a minute for each page.
whether it is possible to reduce this time using phantomjs or i need to use another tool for this?

Comment: I tried to turn off loading css and images. This reduces the time a little

Comment: Here's an idea: don't spin up many processes. Pass the whole array to a single process (or load balance across many processes) and let it do the work.

Answer (score 0):

On some sites I've found this benefits the load time on Phantom JS.
on other sites the images still come up and it makes no difference.

```
page.settings.loadImages = false;
```